# Codeception not detecting a field which appears in the source

Tags: laravel, codeception

I'm using codeception to write acceptance tests for a laravel application. The application is a simple CRUD app, and my tests just test filling out and submitting the application's various forms. I have a working test which creates a new resource but then when I try to edit that same resource I get the following error:

Here's what the (working) test looks like for creating the resource:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Create Additional');
$I->login($I, 'username', 'password');

$I->click('Additional');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/admin/additional');
$I->click('Add Additional');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('admin/additional/create');
$I->see('Add Additional');

 //Fill out form fields
$I->fillField('name', 'Test Name');
$I->fillField('anchor', 'Additional Services in Cusco');
$I->selectOption('publish', '1');

$I->click('Save');
$I->click('Additional');
$I->see('Additional Test Name');

$I->cleanup($I);
```

The test for editing the resource is almost identical:

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Edit Additional');
$I->login($I, 'username', 'password');

$I->click('Additional');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('/admin/additional');
$I->click('Edit');
$I->seeInCurrentUrl('admin/additional/edit/1');
$I->see('Editing');

// Fill out form fields
$I->fillField('name', 'Additional Name Edited');
$I->fillField('anchor', 'Edited anchor');
$I->selectOption('publish', '1');

$I->click('Save');
$I->click('Additional');
$I->see('Additional Name Edited');

$I->cleanup($I);
```

Yet when I run the edit test I get the following error:

```
1) Failed to edit additional in AdditionalEditCept
Couldn't fill field "name","Additional Name Edited":
InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "name"
```

That seems straightforward enough--the "name" field must not be there. But when I look at the source name="name" is there just like it is for the additional/create view. I should point out that codeception didn't detect the field with

```
$I->see('name');
```

either. Here's what the relevant code looks like in AdditionalEditCept.fail.html

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name">Additional Name:</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="" autocomplete="off" name="name" type="text" value="Edited Additional Services in Cusco" id="name">
</div>
```

It seems really simple; codeception needs to find html elements by CSS selectors, I give them a CSS selector. What could be going on here?

Comment: A bit late on this. Have you tried to change the input name `name` to something other than that?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this but I've had a similar error if my html isn't valid eg

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Additional Name:</label>
    <input name="name" type="text">
</div>
</div>
```